# Divide webapps between tomcat instances

Tags: tomcat, load-balancing, mod-jk

I have 300 webapps in a single Tomcat. It takes a while to restart Tomcat  plus a few other limitations. I have Two web servers load balanced in current Apache + Mod_JK + Tomcat setup.

These servers has enough memory/ ready to add extra memory to the servers.

Is it a good solution to launch a second Tomcat instance and divide these webapps between these two Tomcat instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a good idea. There are other benefits such:

- allocating specific resources to each instance
- preventing bad code from impacting all apps
- reduced maintenance impacts from app code changes